# Is it possible to determine whether a read from SecureStream will block?

Tags: .net, networking, stream, network-programming

Can I determine whether reading a single byte from a `SecureStream` will block? The underlying stream is a `NetworkStream`, which has the `DataAvailable` property, but I expect that the `SecureStream` needs to buffer bytes to operate correctly, so I don't think I can rely on the underlying stream's `DataAvailable`.

Alternatively, is there any way to perform a `Read` that will never block? I'm pretty sure there isn't; I've always hated this about the `Stream` API, but maybe I'm missing something?

**Why:** we have a TCP server implementation with highly optimized paths for handling requests. In particular, the original code always used `BeginRead` for every request, but I found that replacing this with a `Read` whenever data was already available (which happens all the time with short requests) increased our maximum throughput by more than 20%. I'd like to do the same for the SSL variant of this code.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why `Read` is so much faster than `BeginRead` when data is available. It shouldn't be that drastic.

You can look at the underlying stream's available data, and if it's more than a few bytes, you can assume data is available and use `Read`. Otherwise, use `BeginRead`. To be on the safe side, set a `ReadTimeout` to a millisecond, so you won't block for long in case you miss.

But I think the real question is why BeginRead is slower in the first place.

Comment: Oh sure, it's not like it's 50ms slower, no. But it does make a difference between 4000 and 5000 requests per second. At that scale, I think it's understandable that it's very slightly slower. Also, do you have a specific suggestion for how many "a few" is?